# Добавление блока относительно текущего

Tags: javascript, html

Есть блок ( https://codepen.io/antoha-sozon/pen/BGLKGQ ). Если в нём нажать на кнопки "вправо" или "вниз" - добавится блок относительно главного. Но, в добавленных блоках не нажимаются кнопки. Подскажите, как клонировать блок?

```js
var addRight = document.getElementById("addRight");
var addBottom = document.getElementById("addBottom");

var controlBlocks = document.getElementById("controlBlocks");

addRight.onclick = function() {
  var innerControlBlock = document.getElementById("innerControlBlock");
  var clone = innerControlBlock.cloneNode(true);
  var rect = clone.getBoundingClientRect();
  clone.style.left = rect.left + '270px';
  controlBlocks.appendChild(clone);
}

addBottom.onclick = function() {
  var innerControlBlock = document.getElementById("innerControlBlock");
  var clone = innerControlBlock.cloneNode(true);
  var rect = clone.getBoundingClientRect();
  clone.style.top = rect.top + '270px';
  controlBlocks.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
.control-blocks {
  position: relative;
}

.inner-control-block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inner-control-block a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inner-control-block a:first-child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.inner-control-block a:last-child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="controlBlocks" class="control-blocks">
  <div id="innerControlBlock" class="inner-control-block">
    <a id="addRight">Вправо</a>
    <a id="addBottom">Вниз</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А ничего что вы клонируете блоки, а вместе с ними клонируются уникальные идентификаторы?=)

Comment: думал уже об этом, а как сделать что бы айдишники новые были и на них вешались события

Comment: @АнтонСозоненко если элемент не уникален или предполагается его клонирование, то нужно использовать _class_, a не _id_.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var controlBlocks = document.querySelector('.control-blocks');

  function fAddBlock(e) {
    let clone = this.cloneNode(true);
    let rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (e.target.classList.contains('addRight')) {
      clone.style.left = rect.left + 270 + 'px';
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains('addBottom')) {
      clone.style.top = rect.top + 270 + 'px';
    }
    clone.addEventListener('click', fAddBlock);
    controlBlocks.appendChild(clone);
  }

  document.querySelector('.inner-control-block').addEventListener('click', fAddBlock);
}
```

```css
.control-blocks {
  position: relative;
}

.inner-control-block {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.inner-control-block a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inner-control-block a:first-child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.inner-control-block a:last-child {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-blocks">
  <div class="inner-control-block">
    <a class="addRight">Вправо</a>
    <a class="addBottom">Вниз</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но после 4-5 клика сбиваеться позиция

Comment: @АнтонСозоненко странно... у меня не сбивается. Я оставил все проверки на ваше усмотрение и доработки, ибо отвечал на вопрос, а не делал "под ключ", но у меня и в данном варианте всё работает норм.